# jQuery, Google Maps API, a is null, and a different amount of locations markers showing up each reload

Tags: jquery, google-maps

Well, here's the misbehaving map

**edited to not drive more traffic than necessary to in_dev site**

I don't even know where to begin. Javascript has never been my strong suit, and this is making me pull my hair out.

Here's the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{               

        var options = { 
                maptype: G_PHYSICAL_MAP,                                                
                controls: false,
                zoom: 3         
        };                              

        var shows = new Array();                
        var i = 0;                              

        $('.show-item').each(function() 
        {                                       
                showLocation = $(this).find('.show-location').html();
                description = "<em>" + $(this).find('.show-date').html() + "</em>"; 
                description += $(this).find('.show-title').html();                description += "<br />";
                description += $(this).find('.show-description').html();                
                if($(this).find('.ticket-link').length > 0)                             
                {       
                        description += $(this).find('.ticket-link').html();             
                }                                                                       

                shows[i] = {address: showLocation, html: description};
                i++;
        }); 

        options.markers = shows;

        console.log(options);

        $("#map").gMap(options);
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting 620 status codes back from Google, which means that you're querying too fast --the javascript is asking the GeoCoder for LatLng on your base-level addresses too many times per second.

The solution is to pre-bake the Lat/Lng into the data somehow.  I know it sounds like a pain, but you'll have to do that or add your markers dynamically on a timer.

---

Based on how I read the responses, btw, looks like you can do a batch of 20 at a time -- no more.

Comment: Well, at least you know how to make it work.  Sometimes it is better to know why something isn't working at least (although sometimes ignorance is bliss).  : )